# Shared NTFS partition conflict, files written under Debian gone

Tags: dual-boot, disk, corruption

I have a dual-boot W7-Debian Jessie on my laptop, and a NTFS partition initially left for sharing data between OS and keeping big files. With myself getting used to Linux, rebooting to windows became very occasional.

That's why I did nothing when I noticed the files I was putting on the NTFS partition were not showing up in windows anymore (leading for example to totally wrong disk space left estimation). And one day, Windows had the idea of running the disk checker utility `chkdsk` on start-up, and cleared the partition from all my Linux files.

Do you have any clue of how I can get them back?

Some more information:

- I've lost about 40 files for ~100GB of data
- It might not have deleted the files; just some incorrect pathways. But I cannot see them from Debian as I used to...
- Running a utility to recover files both from Windows or Linux (`ntfsundelete`) fail to show at least one file I've lost (they're plenty, but not the one `chkdsk` made disappear)
- I'm thinking maybe forcing an EXT file recovery tool to try to find something on a NTFS partition?